# How to fix Docker invalid reference format?

Tags: docker

I am trying to run docker inside a shell script. This is what my script looks like :-

```
#!/bin/bash
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
IMAGE=$(aws ecr describe-images --repository-name repo --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]')
echo $IMAGE
docker pull https://<account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo:$IMAGE
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 https://<account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo:$IMAGE
```

But when i run the script, i keep running into

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you see when you do `docker image ls | grep dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle it's failing on the `docker pull` step.

Comment: droop the `https://` docker by default will talk over https. See the details here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thanks. I tried dropping https:// but still running into the same error. :(

Comment: When you `echo $IMAGE`, what has it found?  If you `set -x`, what's the actual failing `docker pull` command, after all variable expansions?

Comment: When i do echo $IMAGE, it returns the tag like this. "a4f5113". hmmm, Inside double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-pull-ecr-image.html):

> The image name format should be registry/repository[:tag] to pull by tag, or registry/repository[@digest] to pull by digest.

so for the pull command you should use:

```
$ docker pull <account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo:$IMAGE
```

then for the run command, you should use:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 <account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo:$IMAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

It was failing because the image tag was being returned inside double quotes. Had to get the output in plain text using :-

`aws ecr describe-images --repository-name repo --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]' --output text`